# C# assignment - class hierarchy

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, variable-assignment, hierarchy

So I have this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        B b = new B();

        A a = new A(); 
        A c = new C();

        I i = new I(); 
        I k = new D();

        J j = new E();
        J d = new D();



        Console.WriteLine(c is B); //this should be true
        Console.WriteLine(i is J); //this should be false
        Console.WriteLine(b is A); //this should be true
        Console.WriteLine(d is A); //this should be false
        Console.WriteLine(d is E); //this should be true
        Console.WriteLine(k is E); //this should be true
        Console.WriteLine(c is I); //this should be false


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

and I need to make a proper class hierarchy so it would work but I don't really know how >.> I know it's about inheritance but I can't get it to compile.

Comment: Can you show us the code for your classes, also

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? Read [ask].

Comment: I have so far:

class A
    {

    }

    class B : A
    {

    }

    class C : B
    {

    }

    class D : I
    {

    }

    class E : J
    {

    }

    class I : J
    {

    }

    class J
    {

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    class A 
    {
    }

    class B : A
    {
    }

    class C : B
    {
    }

    class D : E
    {
    }

    class E : J
    {
    }

    class I 
    {
    }

    class J : I
    {
    }
    [TestClass]
    public class test
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void t()
        {
            B b = new B();

            A a = new A();
            A c = new C();

            I i = new I();
            I k = (I)new D();

            J d = (J)new D();
            J j = (J)new E();


            Assert.IsTrue(c is B); //this should be true

            Assert.IsFalse(i is J); //this should be false

            Assert.IsTrue(b is A); //this should be true

            Assert.IsFalse(d is A); //this should be false

            Assert.IsTrue(d is E); //this should be true
            Assert.IsTrue(k is E); //this should be true

            Assert.IsFalse(c is I); //this should be false
        }
    }
}
```